# how to split table rows in ASP .Net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have HTML Code in a string named gridHTML

```
    <html>
<body>
<style>a{text-decoration:none; color: black;} th { border: solid thin; }

td{text-align: center;vertical-align: middle;font-family: Arial;font-size: 8pt; height: 50px;
border-width: 1px;border-left-style: solid;border-right-style: solid;}

table { border-collapse: collapse; } tr:nth-child(1) { border: solid thin; border-width: 2px;}
tr{ border: solid thin; border-style: dashed solid dashed solid;}
</style>
<div>
    <table >
        <tr class='leftColumnTableHeadO' align='center' style='font-family: Arial; font-size: 8pt; font-weight: normal; width: 100px;'>
            <th scope='col'>TM No.</th>
            <th scope='col' style='width: 83px;'>Filing Date</th>
            <th scope='col'>TradeMark</th>
            <th scope='col'>Class</th>
            <th scope='col'>Jr#</th>
            <th scope='col'>Applicant</th>
            <th scope='col'>Agent / Attorney</th>
            <th scope='col'>Status</th>
            <th scope='col'>City</th>
            <th scope='col'>Logo</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class='lightGrayBg' >
            <td ><a title='View Report' class='calBtn' href='javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContent$grdTradeMarkNumber$ctl02$ctl00&#39;,&#39;&#39;)'>38255</a>                                        </td>
            <td ><span id='MainContent_grdTradeMarkNumber_lblFilingDate_0'>09-12-1962</span>                                        </td>
            <td >IMIDAN</td>
            <td >5</td>
            <td >158</td>
            <td >test</td>
            <td >test</td>
            <td >Registered</td>
            <td >DELWARE</td>
            <td ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr >
            <td ><a title='View Report' class='calBtn' href='javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContent$grdTradeMarkNumber$ctl03$ctl00&#39;,&#39;&#39;)'>188389</a>                                        </td>
            <td ><span id='MainContent_grdTradeMarkNumber_lblFilingDate_1'>09-09-2003</span>                                        </td>
            <td >RAND</td>
            <td >16</td>
            <td >682</td>
            <td >Ttest </td>
            <td >test </td>
            <td >Advertised</td>
            <td >CALIFORNIA</td>
            <td ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class='lightGrayBg' >
            <td ><a title='View Report' class='calBtn' href='javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContent$grdTradeMarkNumber$ctl04$ctl00&#39;,&#39;&#39;)'>207063</a>                                        </td>
            <td ><span id='MainContent_grdTradeMarkNumber_lblFilingDate_2'>11-03-2005</span>                                        </td>
            <td >FP DIESEL</td>
            <td >7</td>
            <td >690</td>
            <td >testtest</td>
            <td >testtest</td>
            <td >Advertised</td>
            <td >-</td>
            <td ></td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to get all rows separately in a list
i am using split method to do this

```
List<string> rows = gridHTML.Split(new string[] { "<tr" }, StringSplitOptions.None).ToList();
```

but the problem is when i look into the list `"<td"` is removed

Is there any (other) way to get all rows in a list ?

Comment: Why do you parse ASP.NET controls as string at all? What is your desired result?

Comment: I can't explain it here :(

Comment: when i use this
 **List<string> rows = gridHTML.Split(new string[] { "<tr" }, StringSplitOptions.None).ToList();**
 <tr is removed in all list

Answer (score 2):

You should not use string methods (or regex) to parse HTML, i recommend [`HtmlAgilityPack`](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/):

```
var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(gridHTML); 
List<HtmlNode> trList = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("tr").ToList();
```

Since it seems that you want to load this table data into a collection, maybe following approach is better for your requirement. It will load the rows and cells into a `DataTable`, even the `DataColumns` are initialized correctly with the table-header values:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
bool firstRowContainsHeader = true;
var tableRows =  doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("tr");
var tableData = tableRows.Skip(firstRowContainsHeader ? 1 : 0)
    .Select(row => row.Descendants("td")
        .Select((cell, index) => new { row, cell, index, cell.InnerText })
        .ToList());

var headerCells = tableRows.First().Descendants()
    .Where(n => n.Name == "td" || n.Name == "th");
int columnIndex = 0;
foreach (HtmlNode cell in headerCells)
{ 
    string colName = firstRowContainsHeader 
        ? cell.InnerText 
        : String.Format("Column {0}", (++columnIndex).ToString());
    table.Columns.Add(colName, typeof(string));
}
foreach (var rowCells in tableData)
{
    DataRow row = table.Rows.Add();
    for (int i = 0; i < Math.Min(rowCells.Count, table.Columns.Count); i++)
    {
        row.SetField(i, rowCells[i].InnerText);
    }
}
```

Comment: i have string variable not text file !

Comment: what is the header for **HtmlAgilityPack**

Comment: Error **HtmlAgilityPack** and **HtmlNode** could not found

Comment: @zulqarnainjalil: i've added the link to my answer. You have to download the dll and add the reference to your project.

Comment: @zulqarnainjalil: i've added another approach that fills a `DataTable` with all data of your table, even column-names are filled correctly.

Answer (score 2):

For this one, you could use Linq To XML easily. ie:

```
var rows = XElement.Parse(gridHTML).Descendants("tr");                           
var cells = rows.Elements("td");
var cellContentsAsString = cells.Select(c => (string)c);
```

etc.

Comment: Linq-To-XML has some issues with HTML entities  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2008/04/25/querying-html-with-linq-to-xml.aspx

Comment: I know. That is why I said "For this one" specifically. Otherwise, I could use SgmlReader to sanitize the Html and still use Linq To XML. I often find myself to make a choice between using Linq To XML and HtmlAgilityPack and I find Linq to be easier maybe because it is easier to add the required namespaces and ponder around.